# Nginx returns 401 for subdirectory index.html

Tags: html, nginx, web, static, subdirectory

I have a website and every time when I try to access the page in a subfolder like 'myDomain.com/privacy-policy', nginx returns me a '401 Authorization Required'.
The website has the following folder structure:

```
-myDomain.com/
  -index.html
  -images/
    -(images..)
  -legal-disclosure/
    -index.html
    -css/
      -(css files..)
  -privacy-policy/
    -index.html
    -css/
      -(css files..)
  -template/
    -templates.min.css
```

The corresponding nginx configuration:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name myDomain.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name myDomain.com;

    ssl_certificate /root/ssl-certs/myDomain.com_ssl_certificate.cer;
    ssl_certificate_key /root/ssl-certs/_.myDomain.com_private_key.key;

    location / {
      root /var/www/html/myDomain.com;
      index index.html;
    }

    location /privacy-policy {
      root /var/www/html/myDomain.com/privacy-policy;
      index index.html;
     }

    location /legal-disclosure {
      root /var/www/html/myDomain.com/legal-disclosure;
      index index.html;
     }
}
```

Does anyone knows why?

Comment: Is it the whole nginx config and there are no other loaded config files? What the nginx process user and what files access rights on files and folders?

Comment: nginx user is 'www-data' and the access rights are the following: `drwxrwx--- 3 www-data www-data  4096 Jan 19 03:43 images
-rw-rw---- 1 www-data www-data 10433 Jan 19 03:43 index.html
drwxrwx--- 3 www-data www-data  4096 Jan 19 03:43 legal-disclosure
drwxrwx--- 3 www-data www-data  4096 Jan 19 03:43 privacy-policy
drwxrwx--- 2 www-data www-data  4096 Jan 19 03:43 template`. There are two additional config files with another server blocks with different server_names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem! I ignored the subdomain 'www.' on my nginx configurations and my links within the website referenced all to 'www.mydomain.com/...'.
Just added two server blocks with 'www.myDomain.com' and redirect them.
Now it works! :D

Comment: No need for 2 more `server` block. Just add `server_name myDomain.com www.mydomain.com;` is fine.